# PHP json_decode is not working with valid json data

Tags: php, json

While parsing the below JSON data with PHP json_decode function, It returns null, since the key names are without double quotes. Can you please help me in resolving this issue. [ex: Instanceid key name, LineageId key names are not embedded with double quotes ]

JSON data:

```
[
{
InstanceId: 1,
LineageId: 1,
ModifiedDate: "/Date(1225229100000+0000)/",
Name: "HP StorageWorks 1000 Modular Smart Array Active/Active",
Status: "Published",
Version: 1
},
{
InstanceId: 3897,
LineageId: 1,
ModifiedDate: "/Date(1278697020000+0000)/",
Name: "HP StorageWorks 1000 Modular Smart Array Active/Active",
Status: "Published",
Version: 2
},
]
```

Comment: Are you using pdo to fetch this data from db?

Comment: Then it's not valid JSON data.

Comment: `valid json data`: says who? It's not valid json

Comment: Even that wont fix the format @Devon

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, you're right.

Comment: the keys should be quoted

Comment: http://www.json.org and http://jsonlint.com What you have looks more like Javascript; an array of two object literals, to be specific.

Comment: How about the extra comma at the end? That's not valid json.

Comment: It is exactly what he says, _"php json_decode **is not working with** valid json data"_!! @seema are you sending this with `<input>`? If so check that it is included in **single quote** like so: `<input type="hidden" value='json_data' />`

Answer (score 2):

The reason this doesn't parse is because it is simply not valid JSON. In order for it to be valid, the member names have to be strings as is shown [in the JSON RFC](http://rfc7159.net/rfc7159#rfc.section.13) and you need to trim the trailing comma in the array.

```json
[
  {
    "InstanceId": 1,
    "LineageId": 1,
    "ModifiedDate": "/Date(1225229100000+0000)/",
    "Name": "HP StorageWorks 1000 Modular Smart Array Active/Active",
    "Status": "Published",
    "Version": 1
  },
  {
    "InstanceId": 3897,
    "LineageId": 1,
    "ModifiedDate": "/Date(1278697020000+0000)/",
    "Name": "HP StorageWorks 1000 Modular Smart Array Active/Active",
    "Status": "Published",
    "Version": 2
  }
]
```

A few good resources to help with JSON:
Linter: http://jsonlint.com/
RFC: http://rfc7159.net/rfc7159
JSON Example: http://json.org/example

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar things happen several times.

Fortunately, there is a function you can call AFTER json_decode which is [json_last_error_msg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php), which tells you much more about what went wrong.

However, I'll give you a few things I see wrong:

- In JSON, the *last* item in a collection (object {} or array []) *doesn't* have a trailing comma.
- It's generally a good idea to encapsulate the document in {} not []. I've seen PHP's json_decode do weird things with that.